# Efficient way to solve homogenous system with complex numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I need to find how many solutions there are for the system:

$$\begin{bmatrix}2+i&3+i&2 \\ 1&4i&5 \\ i+3&5&2-3i\end{bmatrix}x = 0$$

I assume it can be solved using normal row operations - Gausian elimination.

But, its complex and hard with complex numbers.

Therefore the question is: Is there is another, more convenient/smart way to solve such equations?

I obviously prefer a general way and not specific to the question, if there is such.

Comment: Not really. Computing the determinant in some other way besides Gaussian elimination might be less error-prone, but probably no less tedious.

Comment: @Alon: Were you able to use whatever method and get a result?

Comment: I didnt realy try yet, waited for an answer, but probably will have to do row operations...